# Apache Basic Auth with encoded password directly on URL

Tags: apache, authentication, web, basic-authentication, url-encoding

With Apache's basic authorization framework, it's possible to pass the username and password directly on the URL as:

```
https://username:password@domain.com/path
```

My questions is, is it possible to encode (base64 or sha1, or md5, whatever) the password (or both username and password) in the URL?

I've tried the various combinations listed [here on apache.org](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/password_encryptions.html) but they all seem to be valid when used as a header (like `header("Authorization",...)`).

For example, had this worked, the above url would be something like (taking SHA1 as an example):

```
https://username:{SHA}<base64 encoded sha hash>@domain.com/path
```

But this of course isn't working.

Thanks.

Comment: This does not work. You have some general missconception about how encryption actually works and how it is to be applied. You should start reading about that stuff first, I am afraid.

Comment: Who is talking about encryption? I don't know is a better answer. I said encode!! Encode it so that it isn't just text. Why do I want to do that? Well, I haven't said and that is besides the point.

Comment: Ok, you have a point there. But I wonder how you expect to get answers to a question when you do not want to explain your situation and the motivation behind what you ask. I cannot spot any reason why sending a hash as plain text password should make any sense.